# How to find the current uri of geckoView in android?

Tags: android, geckoview

What is the equivalent of `WebView.getUrl()` in GeckoView ?

I was using `webView.getUrl()` for WebView and `xWalkView.getUrl()` for XWalkView.
I would like use GeckoView in my android application, but struck with getUrl part.
Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct way to get the current URL in GeckoView.

To achieve this, you should track the current URL by overriding the `NavigationDelegate.onLocationChange` method. You can see an example of this here: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/01d1011ca4a460f751da030d455d35c267c3e210/mobile/android/geckoview_example/src/main/java/org/mozilla/geckoview_example/GeckoViewActivity.java#1027